# How to reactive a cancelled futuretask in thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading

I use ThreadPoolExecutor to run some actions, at some time I cancelled some future tasks and stored it into a list to arrange some other tasks to do, and after that I want to reactive the saved cancelled future tasks.

But the problem is when I submit the task into the pool, it would not be executed, looks like the cancelled or done flag is saved and recognized by the thread executor, and thus that thread would not be called.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The [FutureTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) implementation maintains the canceled state. Essentially, when the run() method is called again, it does a CAS operation which fails since the state is not runnable and returns immediately without invoking the inner `Callable`'s call() method. I couldn't see a way to retrieve the original Callable out of it or restore the FutureTask to a non-canceled state.

In response to what should you do...
Do you have to cancel them? Why not let them run? If you want priority execution, could you try creating your `ThreadPoolexecutor` with a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) and use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to establish the priority. This will allow tasks to be executed in the proper order since they will be added to the `PriorityBlockingQueue` based on the results of the `Comparator`.

Comment: Thanks, actually I just implemented a custom FutureTask class which hold a reference to the original Runnable then I can re-submit it.

Comment: @virsir, Okay, be careful though. The way FutureTask works within the executor is that despite having canceled it, the FutureTask will be selected for execution. The cancel flag simply converts the run method into a no-op. You have to be sure not to attempt to re-use the same FutureTask instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Runnable` instead of threads. The execution pool can handle a `Runnable` the same way a `Thread`, but a `Runnable` could be rerunned number of times.

Comment: -1: Not an answer. The OP is not using Threads directly, he is using FutureTasks in a ThreadPoolExecutor. All execution pools in the Java library are ThreadPoolExecutors, which is what the OP is already using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a return value you can use a Callable. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html